# Why can't my own server access a site it is hosting? Yet My computer can?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7.5

I have an iis 7.5 server that is hosting an asp.net mvc 2.0.

So I can go to the site on my own computer and it loads up fine. Yet if I try to go with IE 8 on the windows 2008 server I just get a 404 not found.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the Address you are giving to access the website on your server.If you have an static ip to your router and you are using the same static ip from within the LAN ,you may not be able to connect.

Try giving the LAN IP of your server to connect from within the lan or from localhost.